# SSIS Merge Join DB Source to variable invoice and filename

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

[image][image][image][image]I have 5  fields from table1 that need to be joined to a 2 variables that are being passed through Import column.  This process is occurring within a for each loop and looping through invoice.  Within the data flow task I have a data source pulling fields from table1 and key field is Invoice number.  In another source I have a flat file that is within a for each loop that is set to expression to read a variable invoice. Variable invoice is a Invoice number .csv that is in the flat file connection expression.  I'm using the variable invoice number to input into a import column to create a blob.  I'm planning to join the 4 fields from DB source which contains the invoice number and I would like to join that to the flat file source which reads an expression of invoice number and then flows to a import column for the dt_image data type of the invoice.csv file.  How does one use the merge join to join by invoice number for the DB source and flat file then flow into a import column?

Comment: What you try so far ? please add some code and improve your question, be more specific.

Comment: The first sentence in your question doesn't make any sense, and that makes it hard to understand the rest of the question.

Comment: How does one Merge Join DB Source to a flat file that outputs a .csv file in a for each loop?  I will need to tie four fields within a DB Source to a flat file and that file file outputs a .csv file.  The key field for both source is invoice number.  The .csv(goes through the import column) variable goes through a derived column and then an import column. The 4  fields and invoice.csv needs to be inserted into a table and for the appropriate invoice.